# Referencing Previous Column Value As Column Is Created

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to create a column in which each observation equals the value of the previous observation multiplied by an observation in another column plus 1.  I'm trying to create the indx column in the example below.  indx[1] is hard coded as 1.000, but indx[2] = indx[1]*(1+chng[2]).

I've been using mutate in the dplyr library to make new columns, but I don't see how I can reference the previous value of a column as I'm creating it.

Edit: Updated the below example to include to reflect that the data values for i and chng reset to 0 and 0.000 respectively after every 5 observations and that indx would need to reset to 1.000 when this happens as well and begin it's accumulation again.

Example data.table:

```
test <- data.frame(i = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
               ,chng = c(.000,.031,.005,-.005,.017,.000,.012,.003,-.013,-.005,)
               ,indx = c(1,1.031,1.037,1.031,1.048,1,1.012,1.015,1.002,.997))

     i   chng  indx
 1:  0  0.000 1.000
 2:  1  0.031 1.031
 3:  2  0.005 1.037
 4:  3 -0.005 1.031
 5:  4  0.017 1.048
 6:  0  0.000 1.000
 7:  1  0.012 1.012
 8:  2  0.003 1.015
 9:  3 -0.013 1.002
10:  4 -0.005 0.997
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically this is the same as `cumprod(test$chng + 1)`:

```
test %>% mutate(indx = cumprod(chng + 1))
```

giving:

```
  i   chng     indx
1 0  0.000 1.000000
2 1  0.031 1.031000
3 2  0.005 1.036155
4 3 -0.005 1.030974
5 4  0.017 1.048501
```

Regarding the updated question, create a grouping variable `g` and apply the above by group:

```
test %>%
  group_by(g = cumsum(i == 0)) %>%
  mutate(indx = cumprod(chng + 1)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-g)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you need the previous value from a column/variable you're creating. This is a sequential process and one option is to use `Reduce` (instead of a for loop):

```
test <- data.frame(i = c(0:4)
                   ,chng = c(.000,.031,.005,-.005,.017))

test$indx = Reduce(function(x,y) x*(1+y), test$chng, accumulate = T, init = 1)[-1]

test

#   i   chng     indx
# 1 0  0.000 1.000000
# 2 1  0.031 1.031000
# 3 2  0.005 1.036155
# 4 3 -0.005 1.030974
# 5 4  0.017 1.048501
```

For the case where `i` resets you can use this:

```
test <- data.frame(i = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
                   ,chng = c(.000,.031,.005,-.005,.017,.000,.012,.003,-.013,-.005))

library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(i == 0)) %>%   # create a group based on i column
  mutate(indx = Reduce(function(x,y) x*(1+y), chng, accumulate = T, init = 1)[-1]) %>%  # apply the Reduce function to each group
  ungroup() %>%                          # forget the grouping
  select(-group) %>%                     # remove group column
  data.frame()                           # only for visualisation purposes (see the decimals)

#    i   chng      indx
# 1  0  0.000 1.0000000
# 2  1  0.031 1.0310000
# 3  2  0.005 1.0361550
# 4  3 -0.005 1.0309742
# 5  4  0.017 1.0485008
# 6  0  0.000 1.0000000
# 7  1  0.012 1.0120000
# 8  2  0.003 1.0150360
# 9  3 -0.013 1.0018405
# 10 4 -0.005 0.9968313
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work for the example data set I provided. I realize now that I left out an important detail though. Apologies. In the full table, I'm applying this to, the i variable and chng variable reset to 0 after the 167th observation at which point the indx column would need to start back at 1.00 again and in reapply the function for a new set of chng values.

I'm editing the original post to reflect this.